# How to use ElasticSearch with REST API in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am new to .NET. I am facing an issue with the insertion of a document into Elasticsearch using the RESTful API. I get the following error when I trigger the `IndexAsync` method.

> The type arguments for method 'ElasticClient.IndexAsync(IIndexRequest, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Below is the code that I am actually running. Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

```
// add new record into elastic
public bool Add(T item)
{
    try
    {
        //_client.IndexDocument(item);
        return _client.Index(item).Created;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
    
// add new record into elastic in an asynchronous manner
public async Task<bool> AddAsync(T item)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await _client.IndexAsync(item);
        return response.Created;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [ask] and elaborate on how you're "stuck". What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your methods, you are defining the input `T item`, which defines that `item` is of a generic type `T`. There are some references on this, for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters).

The logic inside your methods can only infer the type `T` if you declare:

```cs
public bool Add<T>(T item)
{
... 
} 
public async Task<bool> AddAsync<T>(T item)
{
... 
}
```

In this way, your type parameter `T` can be accessed in the context of your methods.

If this does not solve your problem, please provide some more details on your code and use case.